# how to save separate data for each users using session id dialogflow

Tags: node.js, variables, session, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi I am making a chatbot in which I want to save data for each user in session so right now what's happening is I have one normal variable in code when the user saves something in it, it is available for every user so I want to do something with session-id so data for each user will be different for each session how can I do this? I can save session-id from the incoming response now I don't know how to use session variables in Dialogflow node.js

Comment: In order to understand better what you want to achieve could you give a example what you mean when yo mention you have on  **"normal variable"**? Also, have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-session) documentation page which explains about the session entities? Which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: just a normal variable like python code -->    num @AlexandreMoraes

Comment: Could you explain a use case for using this variable? Such as how will you use it in each chat interaction and the aim of it. Also, have you checked this [page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-session) which describes Session Intents which acquire recognises different intents from the user each session. Lastly, are you following any documentation to build your chatbot ?

Answer (score 1):

For the same user:

- You can save data within the same session/conversation using conversation data (conv.data).
- You can save data across sessions (i.e. if a user re-opens your Action) using user storage (conv.user.storage).

https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/save-data

If you want to have access that's globally available to all users of your Action, you should use a database like Cloud Firestore.